# [Python]Is there a way to find the optimal variable in OLS?

Tags: python, machine-learning, regression

Knows how to use basic OLS using 'statsmodels api'.

However, I don't know how to select appropriate independent variables from among several independent variables.

adding/removing one independent variable will result in a large change in the P value.

The method of checking by removing the largest p value is inefficient and inaccurate.

Do you know how to choose the optimal independent variable through P value?

Comment: This is not a programming question this is a math / stats question...

Comment: I think I misrepresented what I wanted.

The way I want to do it is to automatically extract independent variables with appropriate p values.

Comment: I think he is asking for feature selection!

Comment: If there are many candidate independent variables, it is very difficult to choose the appropriate independent variables.

Comment: I believe there are strategies in Scikit-Learn you can use for feature selecting. Let me write a doze or so

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Scikit-Learn](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/feature_selection.html), and other similar API offers tools to automate feature selection, e.g.[boruta](https://github.com/scikit-learn-contrib/boruta_py). Examples:

```py
# assuming regression problem

# using GenericUnivariateSelect to keep 50% of features 

from sklearn.feature_selection import GenericUnivariateSelect
from sklearn.feature_selection import mutual_info_regression

# X = independent variables, y = dependent variable
X_mutual_information = mutual_info_regression(X, y)

selector = GenericUnivariateSelect(score_func=mutual_info_regression, mode='k_best', param=50)
X_trans = selector.fit_transform(X, y)

print(f"{X.shape[1] - 1} initial features. {X_trans.shape[1]} of them kept")

# Using Decision Tree and SelectFromModel

from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeRegressor
from sklearn.feature_selection import SelectFromModel

regressor = DecisionTreeRegressor()
selector = SelectFromModel(regressor, threshold='median')
X_trans = selector.fit_transform(X, y)

print(f"{X.shape[1] - 1} initial features. {X_trans.shape[1]} of them kept")

# using Recursive feature elimination instead of SelectFromModel

from sklearn.feature_selection import RFECV

selector = RFECV(regressor)
X_trans = selector.fit_transform(X, y)

print(selector.get_support())
```

After getting these features, you can try OLS with them and see if they improved your algorithm.

See also [boruta](https://github.com/scikit-learn-contrib/boruta_py) for more strategies